# Is that possible to modify a function pointer in C language?

Tags: c++, c

I have a function `A(int num)` now. I want to get another function `B(int num)`, which runs another function `C()` before executing `A(num)`. What I intend to write is like

```
typedef void (*function_type)(int); 

function_type attachToFunction(function_type original, void (*additional_function)(void))
{
    /* return a function_type which first runs additional_function, and then runs original(int) */
}
```

However, I don't don't how should I finish the function or if it is possible.

I'm using C and C++ together, so a C++ implementation is also acceptable as long as the function declaration doesn't change.

Comment: It looks like you want a closure.  The best you can do is store the information in a structure, then call a function that takes the structure as an argument, getting the function pointers from that structure.  In C++ you can use a class and make the call a method.

Comment: As Jarod42 and Tom mention, with that `function_type` as return type, it can't carry any other information, like a capturing lambda would. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/6555febvv)

Comment: You need to clarify if this is C or C++ since answers may look very different depending on language in this case.

Comment: Also this sounds like a pretty certain "XY" question. You think that creating a new function type is the correct solution to the actual problem you are trying to solve, but you can't get it working. Instead of asking about how to get the wrong solution to the problem fixed, you should ask about the best solution to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Usualkly in C, such function pointers all include a `void*` parameter for associated data. In C++, you can pack code and data together in a class so it doesn't need that.

Answer (score 1):

Not with a clean way.

You might use global as you cannot capture the parameters with that interface:

```
typedef void (*function_type)(int); 

static function_type g_original = 0;
static void (*g_additional_function)() = 0;

void my_function(int n)
{
    if (g_additional_function) g_additional_function();
    if (g_original ) g_original(n);
}

function_type attachToFunction(function_type original,
                               void (*additional_function)(void))
{
    g_original = original;
    g_additional_function = additional_function

    return my_function;
}
```

Because of the global, you can have only one of that "attached" function at a time.

In C++, you can "capture" the function pointer via template.
Those parameter should be compile-time though

```
template <function_type f, void (*g)()>
void funcT(int n)
{
    g();
    f(n);
}
```

Usage would be similar to

```
void C();
void A(int b);

void (*B)(int) = &funcT<&A, &C>;
```

Comment: Gobal variables shouldn't be considered as "magic solution for everything", and should not be advised to beginners imo.